# Unity bug? Sorting groups need to be set to 1 and back to 0 for transparency sort axis to work correctly (video inside)

Tags: unity-game-engine

VIDEO: https://streamable.com/xhbq1

CONTEXT: I've set the transparency sort Axis to Y=1. I have my playable character in the same sorting group as all collide-able objects (all who individually have a sorting group component on the same layer, with the same order).

THE ISSUE: My character initially appears on top of everything. However if I set each collide-able object's "order in layer" to 1, and then BACK to 0, the sorting works!

SOLUTION: Is my solution simply having a script on every collide-able object to set the order in layer to 1 in awake, then back to 0 in start? Or am I missing something simpler?

Comment: Wow, that's really weird. What version of Unity are you using? Have you submitted a bug report?

Comment: I'm on 2019.1.12f1, experiencing this problem, but the steps in the video do not cause the transparent sorting axis to suddenly behave differently.

Identical Reddit post - https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity2D/comments/9n9o0q/sorting_group_bug_video_inside/